# QR Code Scanner/Decoder in ASP.NET MVC Smartphone Web Application - Cannot Convert from System.Drawing.Bitmap to ZXing.LuminanceSource

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bitmap, qr-code, zxing

I am trying to implement a QR Code scanner and decoder in an ASP.NET MVC Web Application, specifically targeted at smartphone devices.

So far, the user can upload an image, either from their device or by taking a photo at that moment in time using HTML5 and then send it to the server.

From here, I am trying to decode it using ZXing, but keep getting the error:

> Cannot Convert from System.Drawing.Bitmap to ZXing.LuminanceSource

on the highlighted line.

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Temp"), fileName);
file.SaveAs(path);

Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(path);
BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();

//Error is here
Result result = reader.Decode(bitmap);
var decodedData = result.Text;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: compile or run-time error?

Comment: Compile - won't let me build the solution.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of troubleshooting, I realised that I had accidentally installed the wrong package in the NuGet Package Manager. I accidentally installed 'ZXing.Net.Mobile'.

Just ensure that you download 'ZXing.Net' exactly and no other variation - Michael Jahn is the author.

Based on this:
https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/